# Reference has not compile-time usages

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, assemblies

I've been watching over the architecture view of our solution created by ReSharper, when I noticed some of the project references has no *compile-time usages*, does that mean I can change assemblies at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In simple terms, no compile-time usage means that your code will compile even if you remove the reference. You cannot directly derive anything regarding runtime from this statement. It might even be that your application runs perfectly fine if you just remove this reference. It might also be that your reference is somewhat obfuscated and the compiler doesn't know it. This could be because the reference is implementing interfaces that you compile against or you are looking for it manually at runtime (see Florians answer). You could probably also hide it with reflection if you really wanted to. But that would also need to load the assembly manually at runtime.

At compile-time, the compiler will link the new binaries to the corresponding code in the referenced assemblies. This will allow automatically loading the assembly at runtime. It will also copy const values to your assembly.

You can definitely change the referenced assembly between compile- and runtime, although you should tread very carefully. If method signatures changed, compile-time references will break.

At runtime, referenced assemblies will be loaded once you try to interact with them. Once an assembly is loaded, it cannot be unloaded directly. You can only unload AppDomains. So if you want to change assemblies at runtime, look into AppDomains.

So what could be an intended use of those non-compile-time references? The most common architecture that uses this was mentioned by Florian in the other answer: Plugins. Also other dependencies where you want to separate your code from the actual implementation via interfaces. Your project references without compile-time dependencies are then only used to deliver the implementation to the actual application. Otherwise you would need to add this to your delivery and debugging process, which can be a pain depending on your project.

Comment: So I compile my solution with projects in it. They are assemblies now in my working directory. So in my solution I have 2 projects with no compile time usages, does that mean that I can compile 1 of those projects separately(not the entire solution) and now I have working directory(with old version of project 1 assembly) and newly created assembly of project 1. So you are saying I can change newly created assembly with the old one in my working directory with process still running(maybe some little time downtime) by playing with AppDomains?

Comment: The whole point of this is achieving as minimum downtime as possible without needing to start new instance of this process, because for instance my solution might take a lot of time to compile/optimize and etc I don't want to go thru that process every time I make a change on project that has no compile time usages

Comment: Yes if you use AppDomains, you should be able to setup some logic to achieve that. Look at e.g. https://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/500 for some ideas